# Hardcoding or substituting char **argv in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, program-entry-point

I know this will be considered dumb to do, but I'm trying to hard-code command line parameters, rather than modifying a whole bunch of code for testing purposes only.

Existing main function is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Run run(argc, argv);

    return run.exec();
}
```

I would like to hardcode arguments... so this would mean to pass on a new pointer to a pointer (as that is what the run function takes) or to re-write argv?

The data I'm trying to pass...

```
    char *config[] = {
         " --user=temp"
         " --name=Joe"
         " --id=20"
    };
```

What is the safest and most "proper" bass ackwards way to do this?
I would also like the array size to be dynamic so I don't have to define argc manually when calling the function.

I am new to pointers and C in general, so any help is welcome!

Comment: Edit your question to include IDE, OS, etc, because the answer depends on these

Comment: If you planning on using `exec*`-family, the last element in your `argv` variable should be `NULL`, don't forget about that.

Comment: @stackptr What does an IDE, OS, etc. have to do with anything?

Comment: @Rob Most IDEs have a dialog box where you can enter what the command line arguments are to be. Each IDE has a different way of doing this

Comment: @stackptr The question can be answered without regard to any IDE as one person has already shown below.

Comment: `Run run(argc, argv);` is C?  Looks like C++.

Comment: @Rob Oh I see, i misinterpreted the question, I thought the OP was asking how to manipulate the value the OS passes into `argv` itself

Comment: @stackptr Still has nothing to do with any IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just an "array of strings":

```
char *my_argv[] = {
     "myprogram", // most programs will ignore this
     "--user=temp",
     "--name=Joe",
     "--id=20",
     NULL
};
Run run(4, my_argv);
return run.exec();
```

Don't forget that the program name itself counts as an argument, and that there's meant to be a NULL after the last one.

Of course you can, for example, change `"myprogram"` to `argv[0]` if you don't want to hardcode the program name.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't NULL terminating array, so thanks for that for starters. would I just use sizeof to determine argc?

Comment: @user2815333 Well you know the number of arguments so you can just... use that number. But yes there are tricks you could do with `sizeof` to get the compiler to figure it out.